# The body of view to be destroyed gets called (but it shouldn't)

Tags: ios, swiftui

While verifying how binding invalidates a view (indirectly), I find an unexpected behavior.

- If the view hierarchy is

  ```
   list view -> detail view
  ```

  it works fine (as expected) to press a button in the detail view to delete the item.
- However, if the view hierarchy is

  ```
  list view -> detail view -> another detail view (containing the same item)
  ```

  it crashes when I press a button in the top-most detail view to delete the item. The crash occurs in the first detail view (the underlying one), because its body gets called.

To put it in another way, the behavior is:

- If the detail view is the top-most view in the navigation stack, its body doesn't get called.
- Otherwise, its body gets called.

I can't think out any reason for this behavior. My debugging showed below are what happened before the crash:

- I pressed a button in top-most detail view to delete the item.
- The `ListView`'s body got called (as a result of `ContentView` body got called). It created only the detail view for the left item.
- Then the first `DetailView`'s body get called. This is what caused the crash. *I can't think out why this occurred, because it certainly didn't occur for the top-most detail view*.

Below is the code. Note the `ListView` and `DetailView` contains only binding and regular properties (they *don't* contain observable object or environment object, which I'm aware complicate the view invalidation behavior).

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var value: Int
}

// Note that I use forced unwrapping in data model's APIs. This is intentional. The rationale: the caller of data model API should make sure it passes a valid id.
extension Array where Element == Foo {
    func get(_ id: Int) -> Foo {
        return first(where: { $0.id == id })!
    }

    mutating func remove(_ id: Int) {
        let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        remove(at: index)
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1, value: 1), Foo(id: 2, value: 2)]
}

struct ListView: View {
    @Binding var foos: [Foo]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(foos) { foo in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(foos: $foos, fooID: foo.id, label: "First detail view")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(foo.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var foos: [Foo]
    var fooID: Int
    var label: String

    var body: some View {
        // The two print() calls are for debugging only.
        print(Self._printChanges())
        print(label)
        print(fooID)

        return VStack {
            Text(label)
            Divider()
            Text("Value: \(foos.get(fooID).value)")
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(foos: $foos, fooID: fooID, label: "Another detail view")
            } label: {
                Text("Create another detail view")
            }
            Button("Delete It") {
                foos.remove(fooID)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        ListView(foos: $dataModel.foos)
    }
}
```

**Test 1**: Start the app, click on an item in the list view to go to the detail view, then click on "Delete It" button. This works fine.

The view hierarchy: list view -> detail view

**Test 2**: Start the app, click on an item in the list view to go to the detail view, then click on "Create another detail view" to go to another detail view. Then click on "Delete It" button. The crashes the first detail view.

The view hierarchy: list view -> detail view -> another detail view

Could it be just another bug of `@Binding`? Is there any robust way to work around the issue?

Comment: let me fist ask whether the force unwrap is really necessary?? that's where it crashes .... secondly: I did get to a working solution **with** the force unwrap, but its using slightly different architecture: no Bindings, but EnvironmentObject – would that be of interest?

Comment: @ChrisR Thanks for looking into it. I prefer to the forced unwrapping because in my opinion it's an architecture issue on caller side if it just do trial and error. Paulw11 has given an ObservableObject based answer and I'm about to accept it. Is your answer different? If yes, you're more than welcome to post it. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, I did. It's only different in keeping your array extension.

Comment: Thank you too. I'll post a version using Binding soon. BTW, Binding and Observedobject (or EnvironmentObject) invalidate views in different ways. I'll describe it briefly in my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your data model rather than performing procedural code in your views.  Also, don't pass items by `id`; Just pass the item.

Because you use the `id` of the `Foo` instead of the `Foo` itself, and you have a force unwrap in your `get` function, you get a crash.

If you refactor to use your model and not use ids it works as you want.

You don't really need your array extension. Specialised code as an extension to a generic object doesn't look right to me.

The delete code is so simple you can just handle it in your model, and do so safely with conditional unwrapping.

```
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1, value: 1), Foo(id: 2, value: 2)]
    
    func delete(foo: Foo) {
       if let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
           self.foos.remove(at: index)
       }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DataModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.foos) { foo in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(model: model, foo: foo, label: "First detail view")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(foo.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DataModel
    var foo: Foo
    var label: String

    var body: some View {
        // The two print() calls are for debugging only.
        print(Self._printChanges())
        print(label)
        print(foo.id)

        return VStack {
            Text(label)
            Divider()
            Text("Value: \(foo.value)")
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(model: model, foo: foo, label: "Another detail view")
            } label: {
                Text("Create another detail view")
            }
            Button("Delete It") {
                model.delete(foo:foo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was aware that it's suggested to use value, instead of id, in SwiftUI programing. But I had some misunderstanding until I looked at your code (I read through Apple's demo app before but I never realized it). It's OK to access data model in Button action code, it's just not to do it in view rendering code! See more comments in my answer below.

Comment: You can further simplify this code by using the environment rather than passing the model everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very much like Paul's approach. I just kept the Array extension with the force unwrap as in OP.

```
struct Foo: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var value: Int
}

// Note that I use forced unwrapping in data model's APIs. This is intentional. The rationale: the caller of data model API should make sure it passes a valid id.
extension Array where Element == Foo {
    func get(_ id: Int) -> Foo {
        return first(where: { $0.id == id })!
    }

    mutating func remove(_ id: Int) {
        let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        remove(at: index)
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1, value: 1), Foo(id: 2, value: 2), Foo(id: 3, value: 3)]
}


struct ListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: DataModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(dataModel.foos) { foo in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(foo: foo, label: "First detail view")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(foo.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: DataModel

    var foo: Foo
    var label: String
    
    var body: some View {
        // The two print() calls are for debugging only.
        print(Self._printChanges())
        print(label)
        print(foo.id)
        
        return VStack {
            Text(label)
            Divider()
            Text("Value: \(foo.value)")
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(foo: foo, label: "Yet Another detail view")
            } label: {
                Text("Create another detail view")
            }
            Button("Delete It") {
                dataModel.foos.remove(foo.id)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ListView()
            .environmentObject(dataModel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version. It's best to pass the model around so you can use array subscripting to mutate.

I also changed your `id` to `UUID` because that's what I'm used to and changed some vars that should be lets.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: Identifiable {
    //var id: Int
    let id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}

// Note that I use forced unwrapping in data model's APIs. This is intentional. The rationale: the caller of data model API should make sure it passes a valid id.
//extension Array where Element == Foo {
//    func get(_ id: Int) -> Foo {
//        return first(where: { $0.id == id })!
//    }
//
//    mutating func remove(_ id: Int) {
//        let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
//        remove(at: index)
//    }
//}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    //@Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1, value: 1), Foo(id: 2, value: 2)]
    @Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(value: 1), Foo(value: 2)]
    
    func foo(id: UUID) -> Foo? {
        foos.first(where: { $0.id == id })
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    //@Binding var foos: [Foo]
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                //ForEach(foos) { foo in
                ForEach(dataModel.foos) { foo in
                    NavigationLink {
                        //DetailView(foos: $foos, fooID: foo.id, label: "First detail view")
                        DetailView(dataModel: dataModel, foo: foo, label: "First detail view")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(foo.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    //@Binding var foos: [Foo]
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: DataModel
    //var fooID: Int
    let foo: Foo
    let label: String

    var body: some View {
        // The two print() calls are for debugging only.
        print(Self._printChanges())
        print(label)
        //print(fooID)
        print(foo.id)

        return VStack {
            Text(label)
            Divider()
            //Text("Value: \(foos.get(fooID).value)")
            if let foo = dataModel.foo(id:foo.id) {
                Text("Value: \(foo.value) ")
            }
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(dataModel: dataModel, foo: foo, label: "Another detail view")
            } label: {
                Text("Create another detail view")
            }
            Button("Delete It") {
                //foos.remove(fooID)
                if let index = dataModel.foos.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == foo.id } ) {
                    dataModel.foos.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // no need for @ here because body doesn't need to update when model changes
    //@StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        //ListView(foos: $dataModel.foos)
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have two comments: 1) my binding approach can also use array subscript to mutate (I belive). 2) I understand why you use those `if` statements in `DetailView.body`. I used to do it the same way, but I think that's not the approach Apple suggested in its demo app. I'd like to use Apple's recommended approach because it's simpler and better. Feel free to correct me if you have different opinions.

Comment: 1) cool. 2) since we have a let foo in the body taking advantage of passing value types around we don't even need to look it up by id.

Comment: I see your point. I supposed the reason why you call `dataModel.foo(id:)` to retrieve foo by id, rather than just use the `foo` property, was because the foo property may not contain the up-to-date value, right? I'm not 100% sure yet, but I think using binding may avoid the issue *without* using `if` statement (Unfortunately I don't have code to share yet, as I'm still investigating this possibility).

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that uses Paul's approach but still uses binding. *Note both versions don't really "solve" the issue (the behavior I described in my original question still exists) but instead "avoid" the crash by not accessing data model when rendering the view hierarchy in the body.* I think this is a key point to use a framework successfully - don't fight it.

Regarding the use of binding in the code example, I'm aware most people use `ObservableObject` or `EnvironmentObject`. I used to do that too. I noticed the use of binding in Apple's demo app. But I may consider to switch back to the view model approach.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var value: Int
}

// Note that I use forced unwrapping in data model's APIs. This is intentional. The rationale: the caller of data model API should make sure it passes a valid id.
extension Array where Element == Foo {
    func get(_ id: Int) -> Foo {
        return first(where: { $0.id == id })!
    }

    mutating func remove(_ id: Int) {
        let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        remove(at: index)
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1, value: 1), Foo(id: 2, value: 2)]
}

struct ListView: View {
    @Binding var foos: [Foo]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(foos) { foo in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(foos: $foos, foo: foo, label: "First detail view")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(foo.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var foos: [Foo]
    var foo: Foo
    var label: String

    var body: some View {
        // The two print() calls are for debugging only.
        print(Self._printChanges())
        print(label)
        print(foo)

        return VStack {
            Text(label)
            Divider()
            Text("Value: \(foo.value)")
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(foos: $foos, foo: foo, label: "Another detail view")
            } label: {
                Text("Create another detail view")
            }
            Button("Delete It") {
                foos.remove(foo.id)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        ListView(foos: $dataModel.foos)
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should avoid use if force unwrapping. If you were on my team and I was reviewing your code, I would reject it. By all means use ids if you want, but you need to handle optionality safely. The other problem with this solution is you are tightly coupling your view and your model. The fact that your model uses an array is an *implementation detail* that the view should neither know nor care about.

Comment: Also, from a style point of view, your array extension isn't great either. An extension that is typed to a specific element on a generic like array doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the comments. I understand your point. But I have different opinions. 1) force unwrapping. I use it because I think t the caller should know what it's doing, it shouldn't just blindly call data model API. If this is a distributed system, the API should be lenient. But in this case, I (the app developer) has control on all components (I suppose SwiftUI's API works in a predictable way and I have control on how to call its APIs. In this sense I have control on SwiftUI also), the force unwraping is part of the design. It's effectively a `guard` statement in API entry point.

Comment: 2) Passing id vs value. There is one thing that needs clarification. Are you talking about passing param to View, or passing param to data model API? I meant the former in my answer above. And I think you do the same in your code (that is, passing value to view).  BTW, I have been looking at the code at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training, which uses neither optional nor force unwrapping. That's something I tried to achieve.

Comment: 3) Exposing data model details to view. I see your point and I gave a bad example. Let me make two very minor change to it. First I create a type alias to `[Foo]`. Second I claim the type alias part of the data model API. With these changes (there are no actual change to the code), I think the issue you mentioned is gone. BTW, I figured out this approach by looking at the code in above link.

Comment: 4) Using environment object/observable object vs binding. This is related to the topic about using id vs value. If you uses id, it may be invalid when you pass it to environment object/observable object. Of course, if you don't do force wrapping in the data model API, it won't crash. But you still need to check if the return value is nil.

Comment: 5) I agree your comment on the array extension. It's a hack in the example code.

Comment: I am talking about passing `id` anywhere. You shouldn't really need to pass it to the view or the model. Pass an instance of `Foo` and you can always get the `id` if you need it. I stand by my statement around force unwrap. As careful as you think you are being, you have seen how it caused a crash. If you avoid the force unwrap then you don't crash. If you pass an instance of `foo` you never need `get` and `remove` doesn't need to force unwrap because if the `foo` isn't found then it doesn't matter; the result is the same the `Foo` instance isn't in the model after `remove` is called.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a type alias. There is nothing wrong with your model exposing an array of `Foo`.  The problem occurs when your view tries to operate on the array (calling `foos.remove`. The view needs to ask the model to remove the foo. The model could, for example, store Foos is some other structure and expose an array for convenience. The Foo might need to be removed from some other store or a server.  Maintain separation of concerns between your view and your model and you will find working with SwiftUI works much better

Comment: I think we have different opinion about what's data model. In your viewpoint, you think the observable object is the data model. In my viewpoint, I think the value type embedded in the observable object is also data model. I believe both make sense. Your approach is the traditional view model approach. My approach is the approach Apple recommends in its demo apps.

Comment: They are both data models. However as your app becomes more complex it is important that your view model is the repository for both data and business logic. I wouldn't say that Apple's apps represent best practice.  They are intended as an introduction. This necessitates some simplification.

Comment: I agree your comments. I thought about Apple's approach and the usual view model approach a lot and changed my mind again and again. My current thought is that Apple's approach in not feasible in most practical apps. For those apps they have to access data model in view rendering code. So my statement that one shouldn't access data model in view rendering code is wrong. And if we do that, your suggestion about not doing force unwrapping is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI. I modified my answer. The main thing I removed is this line: "it should be avoided is to access data model in view rendering code". With more lenient data model API, it's a non-issue.